# JIRA plugin to manage queues of issues

Tags: notifications, queue, jira, issue-tracking

I need a JIRA plugin to **manage queues** of issues and notify issue watchers in case the position of an issue in the queue changes. I use old **JIRA 4.2**, thus, I need a solution for this version of JIRA.

Queue management is pretty much the same as backlog management — I need to order the issues manually with a UI (with drag and drop, preferably).   I can have many queues, though.

Another important requirement is that issue watchers get notified when the issue changes it's position in queue.  The later can happen either because someone adds an issue to the queue in front of the issue or some other issue in front is taken out.

I know there is an Agile Plugin for JIRA, but I don't know whether it can do what I want. It's hard to tell by reading the white papers. I do not want to loose time on trying. Maybe there are people who has already implemented a similar set up with JIRA.

Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for JIRA 4.2.  There was a solution for 5.1, developed by mail.ru guys. However, the mail.ru queue management plugin didn't have a notification functionality.

So we ended up upgrading to JIRA 5.1 and extending the functionality to notify stakeholders of queue changes: whenever the position of the issue in the queue changes, watcher are notified.  This automation tools significantly reduced the workload on the product owner to coordinate priorities among the parties.

Here is the source code: https://github.com/ITAttractor/jira-ticket-queue-plugin